# Distinguishing Like Named Files In a Span

Tags: c#

I'm looping through file names in a directory where files have a main extension ".123". The file is split into spans which have extension ".456" and are named like the main file but with a varying number sequence at the end.

I am given the main file name "CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File.123" and need to find all span files as well. The problem I am facing is if there are two files that are named almost identically I end up catching all the files.

> CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File.123
>   CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File001.456
>   CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File002.456
>   CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File002.456
>   CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File-Thats-Almost-Identical.123
>   CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File-Thats-Almost-Identical001.456
>   CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File-Thats-Almost-Identical002.456
>   CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File-Thats-Almost-Identical002.456

I'm using some pretty basic and limited code to accomplish the results I currently have.

```
public static string[] GetFilesInDirectory(string FileName, string Path)
{
    string[] FilesInPath = { "" };
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        FilesInPath = Directory.GetFiles(Path);
        foreach (string FileInPath in FilesInPath)
        {
            if (FileInPath.IndexOf(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName)) > -1)
            {
                results.Add(Path.GetFileName(FileInPath));
            }
        }
        FilesInPath = null;
        return results.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return results.ToArray();
    }
}
```

If I call function `GetFilesInDirectory('CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File.123', 'C:\')` it returns all of the files.

Is there a better more accurate way to accomplish this?

UPDATE:

I wrote some logic using some suggestions from the answer:

```
public static string[] GetImageFilesInDirectory(string FileName, string Path)
{
    string[] FilesInPath = { "" };
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        FilesInPath = Directory.GetFiles(Path, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName) + "???.???", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (string FileInPath in FilesInPath)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(FileInPath).ToLower() == Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToLower())
            {
                if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileInPath) == Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName))
                {
                    results.Add(Path.GetFileName(FileInPath));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (FileInPath.IndexOf(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName)) > -1)
                {
                    results.Add(Path.GetFileName(FileInPath));
                }
            }
        }
        FilesInPath = null;
        return results.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return results.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is modifying the naming schema an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit what `Directory.GetFiles` returns by giving it a search pattern like `CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File???.456`.

```
resutls = Directory.GetFiles(
    Path, 
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName) + "???.456").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(), which ignores the ".xxx" portion of the filename and will also return any file that has "CustomerName_123456_Name-of-File" in it.

Easy solution is to call Path.GetFileName() with the full name of the file needed, assuming you are looking for a particular file, and not trying catch several files.